# Mongo: filter after projection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working with pymongo. One of my fields is: `published_date` which is a string formated as `2020/03/10 07:20:09`

I'm able to convert this value to a datetime using the following aggregate:

```
isodate = datetime.now()
pipeline = [
    {'$limit': 2},
    {'$project': { 
        'date':'$published_date',
        'date2': {
            '$dateFromString': {
                'dateString': '$published_date',
                }
            },
        }
    }
]
cursor = TEST_COLLECTION.aggregate(pipeline)
list(cursor)
```

where `date2` is the value converted to datetime (working already).
Now, the list of documents should be filtered such as the `date2 >= isodate`
I've tried to do it by implementing:

```
'date2': { 
                '$filter': {
                    'input': {
                        '$dateFromString': {
                            'dateString': '$published_date',
                            }
                        },
                    'as': "date2",
                    'cond': { 
                        '$gte': ['$$date2', isodate] 
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

but it sems it is not working since i get the following error:

> OperationFailure: input to $filter must be an array not date

**Update**
As asked in the comments, the data consists of documents with several fields, `published_date` being one of them. I expect as an output a list of documents that comply with the filter of `published_date >= datetime.now()`.

Maybe the solution is not a pipeline but I'm not sure since it is my first time with `aggregates`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Checking mongodb documentation. I think you should write in cond, something like this ```'$cond': { '$gte': ['$$published_date', isodate }``` Check the example section in [filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: yeah, this helps a bit, I have updated the code with error

Comment: What exactly are you trying to filter? The pipeline makes no sense to be honest. $filter is to filter an array within each document. $dateFromString is a date, not an array. There is nothing to filter there. The error message says that precisely.

Comment: The problem is, you are not passing an array to `$filter`'s `input` parameter. You are just passing the date, which is converted from string. Could you show how your data looks like and what is your expected output?

Comment: @AlexBlex, I'm trying to get documents that have a date greater or equal to `datetime.now()`

Comment: @ngShravil.py updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget $filter. It serves different purpose. 
You want an extra $match stage in the pipeline to filter out **documents** produced by the $project stage:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$limit': 2},
    {'$project': { 
        'date':'$published_date',
        'date2': {
            '$dateFromString': {
                'dateString': '$published_date',
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {'$match': {'date2': {'$gte': isodate}}}
]
```

assuming your `isodate` is a valid date object.